# Angular-piwik ngp-set-site-id

Tags: angular, matomo

I'm new to piwik and I'm using the angular-piwik service. In [Mike-spainhower's Readme](https://github.com/mike-spainhower/angular-piwik) there's this piece of code

```
ngp-set-site-id="<id>"
```

When I put the id in a static way (for eg: `id="1"`) it works but when I try to put it in a variable to be dynamic (in a properties file) it doesn't work. I tried to print it, and it's the same.

I though it was a problem with the data type, I tried to parse in int and string but it didn't work.

Did someone encounter the same problem?

Comment: Could you link the readme you reference and maybe include code snippets for how you've tried setting it dynamically?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I actually found the answer, when putting the id in a variable we have to call it like this ngp-set-site-id="**{{yourVarId}}**"

Comment: That's fantastic! Feel free to add it as an answer below and accept it, so it's easier to figure out if someone else has this issue in the future :)